# How to connect an SOAP API in PHP of Boondmanager ERP with Talend

Tags: api, soap, wsdl, talend

I want **connect** my BoondManager ERP with Talend. I need to Extact the Database of Boond.

I tried to use WSDL file.but i couldn't retrieve the schema

I wanna really just **establish the connection** between the Boond Aplication and talend to extract Data. Can i find someone who has already worked on that ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a tESBConsumer component to connect to your application through SOAP . Just give the WSDL address or file, and in the service configuration popup, select 'populate schema to repository on finish' to get your request/response schema, that you'll be able to use with tXMLMap before and after your tESBConsumer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried that. but i don't know how to retrieve the schema. i get just payload-> root(loop) in the input. can you show me more how can i do ? Thanks

Comment: in the tXMLMap, rightclick on your 'payload' element , then 'Import From Repository'. If the 'populate schema to repository' step is OK, you should access your metadata

Comment: Thank You Corentin for your help ! I don't know if you made the same process with Boond, because i serach to call the ReadBDD method. So, i have just PublicService to choose. I will be very grateful if i can solve that.